# How can I increase font size in Chalk for Node JS?

Tags: node.js, chalk

How can I increase font size in Chalk for Node JS?  I wanted to do this with my code. This makes obviously the England flag but I want to add some text underneath saying it's coming home. Don't know looked on many gits and forums but couldn't find anything already asked.

```
const chalk = new require('chalk').constructor({ enabled: true, level: 3 });

console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);

console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);

console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.red.bgRed
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.red.bgRed('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.red.bgRed
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.red.bgRed('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.red.bgRed
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.red.bgRed('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
console.log(
        chalk.white.bgWhite
    ('...........................') +
      chalk.red.bgRed('2222222') +
        chalk.white.bgWhite('...........................')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

`chalk` works using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and there are no (portable) codes to change font size.